# Disable the admin bar for specific user

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a WordPress site. There are many users. I want when an author logs in, the author who currently is currently logged on couldn't access the "edit page" menu in the admin bar.

Is there any plugin to disable that?

Comment: Do you want to remove the bar, or the entire *privilege* to edit pages? Who should be able to edit pages then, just administrators?

Comment: belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, I want it for admin, but not for the author user.

Comment: In other words you want **to lock the ability to post and perform any changes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-bar-disabler/

OR Alternative and manual way is under if condition place this

```
show_admin_bar(false);
```

E.g.

```
if(!is_admin())
{
    show_admin_bar(false);
}
```

place this code in functions.php so that it will disable the admin bar for all the other users.

Comment: Note however that this doesn't protect from authors editing content; it just removes the most obvious way to open the "edit" page.

Comment: In fact why avoiding author to edit content? Just change his role no?

Answer (score 1):

In your `functions.php` file, you can add one of the following code snippets to get the indicated results:

// Only display to administrators

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

// Disable for specific role (in this case, 'subscriber')

```
function remove_admin_bar() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if (in_array(‘subscriber’, $user->roles)) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```